# Turn off Android Studios bad style advice?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to remove all of Android Studios "This can be changed to" warning flags. I know I can reduce all the warning flags with the slider from inspections to Syntax.

I don't know if Syntax covers every non style warning, or if it also includes actual warnings. If it does, can you link me the documentation that says so? I need actual hard proof. I can't find much talking about the syntax warning highlighting.

I can ignore these, no problem but I'm seeing that my team is treating these like real warnings. When you take an existing code base and a team.. we waste a ton of times with hundres of personal style errors. I like to do if(boolean == false), Because it's CLEAR. A lot of these suggestions make the code, bleedin edge 1980s style, save every character efficient, but as readable as.. well.. 1980s code..

For example, we just spent half an hour trying to figure out if we had an error in an if statement, because it "could" have simplified it sorta.

Or my favorites where it tells you to change it, then tell you to change it back..

Also yes I know I can add suppressions, which cause errors in my coworkers Eclipse. . .

Comment: Still need a solution....

Comment: Hmm.. This is still a daily pain for me.

Comment: +1 for exp == false its is more clear than !exp 
Anyone knows why a lot of people say it is better to write !exp ?

Comment: I'm sure the answer has to do with speed of execution. Though I would be shocked if the compiler doesn't optimize it.

Answer (score 7):

See if this helps, Preferences → Editor → Inspections,

Disable the those you don't want, eg. Pointless boolean expression under "Control flow issues"

reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this line above the pointless boolean you want to ignore. I use this a lot when using BuildConfig variables as they appear constant but are really not as they are controlled by the gradle build system.

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions,PointlessBooleanExpression
```